# Is this a I IV V ii progression?

Tags: chord-progressions

I'm currently learning a piece that has the following chords in the chorus (one chord per bar):

```
     Em7
     A
     Bm7
     F#m7
```

Am I correct in assuming this is a I-IV-V-ii progression in the key of E minor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, major chords are written in RN capitals, minors in lower case. But, in Em, F#m is not a diatonic chord. I'd say it's more likely in D major, which uses all four chords diatonically. If so, them the RN will be ii, V, vi, iii.